# Janusgraph : Could not instantiate implementation: org.janusgraph.diskstorage.cql.CQLStoreManager

Tags: graph, cassandra, cql, janusgraph

I have an application which is using embedded janusgraph with cassandra as backend database.

Previously, i was connecting using cassandrathrift, and it was working fine. Here are the old configurations:

```
storage.backend=cassandrathrift
storage.cassandra.keyspace=t_graph
```

But i had some problems regarding timeouts. So, i changed the configuration from cassandrathrift to cql. Here is the new configuration:

```
storage.backend=cql
storage.cql.keyspace=t_graph
storage.cql.read-consistency-level=ONE
```

And, now i am getting the following error:

```
> Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
> Could not autowire field: private in.graph.services.GraphService
> in.graph.services.FollowService.graphService; nested exception is
> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
> creating bean with name 'graphService': Invocation of init method
> failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could
> not instantiate implementation:
> org.janusgraph.diskstorage.cql.CQLStoreManager    at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:573)
>   at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
>   at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:331)
>   ... 28 common frames omitted Caused by:
> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
> creating bean with name 'graphService': Invocation of init method
> failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could
> not instantiate implementation:
> org.janusgraph.diskstorage.cql.CQLStoreManager    at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:136)
>   at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsBeforeInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:408)
>   at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1570)
>   at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:545)
>   at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
>   at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
>   at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
>   at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
>   at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
>   at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1192)
>   at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1116)
>   at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1014)
>   at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:545)
>   ... 30 common frames omitted Caused by:
> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not instantiate
> implementation: org.janusgraph.diskstorage.cql.CQLStoreManager    at
> org.janusgraph.util.system.ConfigurationUtil.instantiate(ConfigurationUtil.java:69)
>   at
> org.janusgraph.diskstorage.Backend.getImplementationClass(Backend.java:477)
>   at
> org.janusgraph.diskstorage.Backend.getStorageManager(Backend.java:409)
>   at
> org.janusgraph.graphdb.configuration.GraphDatabaseConfiguration.<init>(GraphDatabaseConfiguration.java:1376)
>   at
> org.janusgraph.core.JanusGraphFactory.open(JanusGraphFactory.java:164)
>   at
> org.janusgraph.core.JanusGraphFactory.open(JanusGraphFactory.java:133)
>   at
> org.janusgraph.core.JanusGraphFactory.open(JanusGraphFactory.java:80)
>   at
> in.graph.services.GraphService.postConstruct(GraphService.java:39)
>   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
> sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>   at
> sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$LifecycleElement.invoke(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:354)
>   at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$LifecycleMetadata.invokeInitMethods(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:305)
```

I have checked the following links for answer:

[link2](https://github.com/JanusGraph/janusgraph/issues/679)

[link2](https://github.com/JanusGraph/janusgraph/issues/468)

But no luck. Please suggest how to solve this.